# Use MonoDevelop C# class in XCode Solution

Tags: xcode, monodevelop

I have a MonoDevelop project with a single class with a static method that I would like to reference and use in a standard Objective-C project in X-Code.  Is this even possible?

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but have have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692813/mixing-c-sharp-with-objective-c?

Comment: Halvard post this as an answer; if this turns out to work I will still give you the bounty.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you targeting iOS or OSX ?

Comment: iOS is the target platform for hte solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert on this, but have you looked at [this question on Mixing C# with Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692813/mixing-c-sharp-with-objective-c)?

(originally posted as a comment)