# Invoking C# from C on Linux

Tags: c#, c, linux, .net-core, pam

Okay, I'm trying to write a Pluggable-Authentication-Module (PAM) written in C#.

As a Proof-of-Concept, I'm trying to re-implement the following simple PAM module in C#:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <security/pam_appl.h>
#include <security/pam_modules.h>

/* expected hook */
PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_setcred( pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv ) {
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_acct_mgmt(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    printf("Acct mgmt\n");
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

/* expected hook, this is where custom stuff happens */
PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_authenticate( pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags,int argc, const char **argv ) {
    int retval;

    const char* pUsername;
    retval = pam_get_user(pamh, &pUsername, "Username: ");

    printf("Welcome %s\n", pUsername);

    if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS) {
        return retval;
    }

    if (strcmp(pUsername, "bob") != 0) {
        return PAM_AUTH_ERR;
    }

    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}
```

I've read about [p/Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(VS.71).aspx), and that it seems I need to write a "wrapper" of some sort. The problem I'm running into is all the examples have a DLL that is wrapped, and I'm not sure what is the equivalent of that here. Isn't PAM compiled into the kernel? How do you "wrap" that?

For those of you shaking your head and asking "Why, but why?"?

The authentication source I'm trying to go against (Azure AD), does not have a C or C++ library, but it does have a C# library. I've been told by Microsoft that I should be able to use the .NET Core on Linux to create the PAM module in C#.

-------------------------- UPDATE ------------------------

Okay, I've learned a bunch of ways that won't work, and I figured I should document them here.

First of all, it does not appear that [Unmanaged Exports](https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/Do-you-know-a-tool-to-automate-making-C-DLLs-exports-callable-from-native-code) will work.

1. The NuGet package that implements this does not run on the dotnetcore and therefore won't run on Linux.
2. ildasm / ilasm which are required for doing this manually appear to only live on Windows.
3. Even those DLL's compiled on Linux do not appear to have an ELF header. Without an ELF header, they apparently can't be used in PAM, and I expect they won't work in any plugin / module interface.

BTW, its worth noting that there is a New Feature Request for .Net Compiler (Code-Name Rosyln) [for Unmanaged Exports to be native](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1013). I don't understand why this doesn't exist yet, but it looks like without the ELF headers even with this it wouldn't work.

We've briefly looked at Mono as @piedar suggested, but it looked like the most complicated option. Its now looking like it might be the only option.

It seems like this should be so much simpler than it apparently is.

Comment: I guess it should be [`DllImport("libpam.so.0")`](https://gist.github.com/martinwoodward/f5b195aa53b4ed52cabaf701486baa79) or similar.

Comment: It's not that simple.  PAM loads .so binaries at runtime and expects them to contain a specific set of C-style functions.  I'd say your best bet is to use [embedded Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/) to invoke the managed assembly.

Comment: @piedar Thank-you. That definitely helps and I'm checking that out. Based on the language you used, I also found this https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/Do-you-know-a-tool-to-automate-making-C-DLLs-exports-callable-from-native-code We're looking down that route too.

Comment: Here is an example of Mono interop that may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692813/mixing-c-sharp-with-objective-c

Comment: Additionally, despite what the title says, it seems to me that you're more looking at invoking C# from C than the other way around.

Comment: @zneak Thank-you for both comments. You're right, I updated the title, and I will check that post out!

Comment: Did you ever manage to make a PAM Module in C#?

Comment: @MrCalvin No, we ended up just writing it in C. Afterwards we did find a few Pam modules in Rust; so that would be an option.